# Blazor SignalR Call Wrong JSRuntime

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I create Event Maped Seat reservation and using SignalR creates a realtime seat update status view

My BroadcastHub

```
public class BroadcastHub : Hub
{
    public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
    public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
    public async Task SeatUpdate(long SectinId, string groupName, long SeatId, SeatStatus seatStatus)
    {
        await Clients.OthersInGroup(groupName).SendAsync("ReceiveSeatUpdate", SectinId, SeatId, seatStatus);
    }

}
```

Component

```
 <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
     @((MarkupString)@SectionData.Salon.SalonMap)
 </div>
      ...Seat Selection Murkup....


@code {
private HubConnection hubConnection;
public bool IsConnected => hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;
Task SeatUpdate(long SectinId, string EventId, long SeatId, SeatStatus seatStatus) => hubConnection.SendAsync("SeatUpdate", SectinId, EventId, SeatId, seatStatus);

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    SectionData.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    SectionData.Salon = await DataService.GetSalon();
    action = GetSection;
        foreach (var item in salon.Sections)
        {
          SectionData.Salon.SalonMap =salon.SalonMap.Replace(item.Action,$"onclick='app.GetSectionCallerJS({item.Id})'");
        }

        #region Hub
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/broadcastHub")).Build();
        hubConnection.On("ReceiveSeatUpdate", async (long SectinId, long SeatId, SeatStatus seatStatus) =>
        {
            if (SectionData.Section.Id == SectinId)
            {
                var Seat = SectionData.Section.Seats.Values.Where(x => x.Id == SeatId).FirstOrDefault();
                Seat.SeatStatus = seatStatus;
            }
            StateHasChanged();
        });
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        await hubConnection.SendAsync("AddToGroup", EventSansUniqueId);
        #endregion Hub
    
}

#region GetSection
private static Action<long> action;
private void GetSection(long SectionId)
{
    var section= salon.Sections.Where(x => x.Id == SectionId).FirstOrDefault();
    SectionData.SetSection(section);
    SectionData.Section.Seats = DataService.GetSection(SectionId);
    StateHasChanged();
}
[JSInvokable]
public static void GetSectionCaller(long SectionId)
{
    action.Invoke(SectionId);
}
#endregion GetSection

public void Dispose()
{
    SectionData.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    if (IsConnected) hubConnection.SendAsync("RemoveFromGroup", EventSansUniqueId);
}


}
```

JavaScript Is

```
window.app = {
  GetSectionCallerJS: (id) => {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('KishApp.TRMS.Salon', 'GetSectionCaller', id);
  }
};
```

The problem is when the hub registers for the second, third, and... time `DotNet.invokeMethodAsync` Call Last registered page, not the one actually calling the method and causing the wrong page update

Comment: Your `JSInvokable` method `GetSectionCaller` and the `action` are static - you need to use an instance method and an instance Action to ensure the code runs in the context of the current component. To do this, you will need to register the current component's DotNetObjectRef with your JavaScript `app` object so it can call it. OR just write the code in Blazor, instead of doing this hybrid JS approach, then you won't need all the interop.

Comment: HI @MisterMagoo, thanks for your reply.for the situation I must do the hybrid because the salon map is SVG loaded from DB so to choosing a section on the map I need the hybrid solution. about  DotNetObjectRef I have been trying to do so but no success with int can you please provide a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tanks to @MisterMango I found that problem `GetSectionCaller` is a static method and I  must have created new `DotNetObjectReference` every time page initial so

```
DotNetObjectReference<Salon> ObjectReference;
  
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    if (firstRender)
    {
        ObjectReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create<Salon>(this);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("app.setObjectReference", ObjectReference);
    }
}

[JSInvokable("GetSectionCaller")]
public void GetSectionCaller(long SectionId)
{
    GetSection(SectionId);
}
```

JavaScript

```
window.app = {
GetSectionCallerJS: (id) => {
    dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('GetSectionCaller', id);
},
setObjectReference: (ObjectReference) => {
    this.dotNetObject = ObjectReference;
}};
```